# Not showing bio tag in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I'm working on a blog page, and I'm creating page about authors but it doesn't work to load bio (short description). I don't know why it wasn't working, please see code below:

this is author_detail.html

```
<p>Bio: {{ author.bio }}</p>
```

this is views.py

```
def author_detail(request, slug):
    user = User.objects.get(username=slug)
    author = Author.objects.get(user=user)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author=user)
    return render(request, 'author_detail.html', {'author': user, 'posts': posts})
```

this is models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, default='', help_text='Enter a short description about yourself.')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self.user.username.lower().replace(' ', '-')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.bio:
            self.bio = "This author hasn't added a bio yet."
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

if I add `print('author.bio')` it gives me in the terminal the bio, but I don't know why it doesn't show up in (html) page... Any idea?

Comment: You are passing `user` here instead of author: `{'author': user, 'posts': posts}`

Comment: Thanks, I did that because if I change it I cannot get user.  This tag `<h2>All posts by {{ author.first_name }}</h2>` doesn't show anything, but `<h2>All posts by {{ user.first_name }}</h2>` shows the user that is logged in. Any idea here?

Comment: You can pass author, and can get the first_name with `{{ author.user.first_name }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already described by [kamran890](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14005534/kamran890) in the above comment.

It should be `author` in `context` not `user` so:

```py
def author_detail(request, slug):
    user = User.objects.get(username=slug)
    author = Author.objects.get(user=user)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author=user)
    return render(request, 'author_detail.html', {'author': author, 'posts': posts})
```

If you want to retrieve `first_name` from `author` instance then use `{{author.user.first_name}}`.

Comment: Thanks, I did that because if I change it I cannot get user.  This tag `<h2>All posts by {{ author.first_name }}</h2>` doesn't show anything, but `<h2>All posts by {{ user.first_name }}</h2>` shows the user that is logged in. Any idea here?

Comment: @mdev you can use `{{author.user.first_name}}` instead. See edited answer.